# Is it is possible to write data to replicated master in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-replication

Master: PC 1MYSQL 5.5
and iam writing some data from MS access tables  to MYSQL tables by using some 3rd party application, every thing works fine.
But once i applied replication settings to my master with the same configuration the data is not getting updated from MS access to MYSQL.
But other tables when iam modifying manually in MYSQL those are getting replicated in slave.
Slave: PC2 MYSQL 5.5

Can anyone pl suggest me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

*Configure the CNF file of master with
**binlog-format=MIXED**

Then the data got transferred from MSAccess to MySQL(replicated Master) via third party communication tool and then from MySQL(replicated Master) to MySQL(Slave)*